# Why does performance.now() and Chrome's performance tools show different results?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I created a quick bit of code to test this. I included this script on my page and refreshed the browser:

```
const startTime = performance.now();
const img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png?' + Math.random();
const endTime = performance.now();
const downloadTime = endTime - startTime;
console.log(downloadTime);
```

The script reports the `endTime` as `0.19000000000005457`. The `endTime` value is an instance of `DOMHighResTimestamp` which [returns a double in milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp).

But the chrome developer tools reports it took 81ms. That's pretty big difference for my problem. If it only took 81ms why does my script report 190ms? Or am I missing something obvious?

[image]

**Edit**

Thanks to Josh's answer for pointing out that it needs to be in the `load` handler. My bad. But sadly the values are still inconsistent.

Also why the downvotes? This is a legitimate question. I need to know down the last detail exactly how long it took to download a specific image for a very specific reason.

Comment: Did you test it multiple times? Maybe it is cached or something

Comment: Yeah I did. It's not caching as I added `Math.random()` to the end of the image URL to ensure the browser doesn't cache.

Comment: Oh nice I didn't notice it at the end

Comment: How is `const downloadTime = endTime - startTime` related to the request properties displayed at `Network` tab at `DevTools`?

Comment: maybe the time indicated by google concerns just the retreiving of the image, and your script times also the creation of the object and the injection in the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<img>` elements are loaded asynchronously. Your code is composed synchronously.

```
const downloadTime = endTime - startTime;
```

has no relation to the request for the resources at `Network` tab at `DevTools`.

You can use [`PerformanceObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver) to get the performance metrics relating to a request for a `"resource"`

```js
const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list, obj) => {
  for (let entry of list.getEntries()) {
    for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(entry.toJSON())) {
      console.log(`${key}: ${prop}`);
    }
  }
});

observer.observe({
  entryTypes: ["resource"]
});

const img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png?' + Math.random();
```

Comment: Perfect! This reports exactly the same times. Except it has no IE support. I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that JavaScript is single threaded — any networking code in particular happens asynchronously through event handlers. Any code that you can read from top to bottom happens more or less instantaneously (barring things like heavy DOM/CSS abuse, or a lot of CPU bound code).

It looks like you want to know how long it took to download the image? Watch for the `load` event on the image.

```js
const startTime = performance.now();
const img = new Image();
img.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const endTime = performance.now();
  const downloadTime = endTime - startTime;
  console.log(downloadTime);
});
img.src = 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png?' + Math.random();
```

An example of code that might happen synchronously would if you then inserted the image into the document and asked for the width/height, which would block while the image is decoded and rendered, and layout happens.

Comment: Thanks Josh. In my original code the endTime was not waiting for the download to complete. Your solution works. The problem is the values are still off. I think you're right though other processes are causing it to display a different time.

Comment: good explanation and example, but results are stil a bit weird, i get  approximatively 150 to 250 when running the first time, and only 60 to 80 when running again. When refreshing with cleaning cache (CTRL+F5), it satrts again with big values (Firefox). Something seems to be definetly put in cache